# Validate string in javascript with parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, escaping, parentheses

I just need to validate 2 strings in javascript.

One of them must contain only 0 or more open parenthesis ( .

The other must contain only 0 or more close parenthesis ) .

This means only those characters are allowed in each value.

After spending a lot of time trying to understand the regex, I can't find a way to achieve this. With the escape characters I make a mess of the regex function.

This is what I thought:

```
/\(*/
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding your requirements, but wouldn't every possible string in existance fit both of those criteria?

Comment: "must contain 0 or more" ... thats like saying it can contain it or not, therefore does not matter.

Comment: Do they need to contain the same amount of respective parentheses?

Comment: So, for the first field, only open parenthesis are allowed. For the second, only closing parenthesis.

Comment: So you mean that the first field can NOT contain closing parenthesis and the second field can NOT contain opening?

Comment: First field: Only allowed characters are open parenthesis. 
Second field: Only allowed characters are close parenthesis.
If there is any other character, validation must fail.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

```
/^\(*$/
```

matches a string that contains nothing but opening parenthesis,

```
/^\)*$/
```

does the same for closing parentheses.

Comment: Thanks so much! so the ^ and $ define that it has to look through all the chain, right? It's working. Thank!

Comment: @Adri: Exactly. The `^` makes sure that the match starts at the beginning of the string, and the `$` does the same for the end of the string.